Fatal error when trying to get method info
I'm new to C# and I am trying to shorten my code.
I am able to get it to work with doing error checking.
But is there an easier / simpler way to error check in my 2nd method's code?
It just seems like a better way to get MethodInfo:
MethodInfo[] methods1 = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .Where(x =>
                    x.IsAssembly != true &&
                    x.ReturnType == typeof(void) &&
                    x.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
                    x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(object) &&
                    x.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(EventArgs))
                .ToArray();

 foreach (MethodInfo method in methods1)
 {
     MethodBody methodBody = method.GetMethodBody();

     if (methodBody == null) 
         continue;

     byte[] array = methodBody.GetILAsByteArray();

     if (array.Length == 0) 
         continue;

     byte[] take = array.Take(7).ToArray();

     if (take.Length == 0) 
         continue;

     byte[] skip = take.SkipWhile(b => b != 0x80).ToArray();

     if (skip.Length == 0) 
         continue;

     bool last = skip.Last().Equals(0x14);
 }

 // This will crash program sometimes because there is no check on SkipWhile
 MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                    .Where(x =>
                        x.IsAssembly != true &&
                        x.ReturnType == typeof(void) &&
                        x.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
                        x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(object) &&
                        x.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(EventArgs))
                     .Where(m => m
                        .GetMethodBody()
                        .GetILAsByteArray()
                        .Take(7)
                        .SkipWhile(b => b != 0x80) 
                        .Last().Equals(0x14))
                     .ToArray();


You are "new to C#" and you are inspecting the IL of a method (?) :)

i have worked on C++ more

Just take the first code? Shorter isn't a quality but readability is.

If I understand correctly, the second approach does not handle a null method body, null IL byte array, or an empty byte array after the skipping and taking.
To handle the nulls, use ?. instead of .. This will make the whole expression null when the LHS is null. See also null conditional operator.
To handle the empty IEnumerable, you can use LastOrDefault instead of Last. This will return 0 (the default value of byte) when the IEnumerable is empty, instead of throwing an exception. Since you are comparing against 0x14, an empty IEnumerable will give you false as you expect.
MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(x =>
        x.IsAssembly != true &&
        x.ReturnType == typeof(void) &&
        x.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
        x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(object) &&
        x.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(EventArgs) &&
        x.GetMethodBody()
            ?.GetILAsByteArray()
            ?.Take(7)
            .SkipWhile(b => b != 0x80) 
            .LastOrDefault() == 0x14
    )
    .ToArray();


didnt know about ?. thanks.
